# How to zoom in in this mandlebrot code

Tags: fractals

I have the following jupyter notebook code that draws a mandlebrot fractal 50 times and saves it in 50 different image files. I would love it if someone could help me figure out how to zoom into the center each image. I messed around with the numbers a good bit, but I would love it if I could zoom in on a point and keep the window steady as well. Thanks!

```
import numpy
from numba import jit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@jit

def mandlebrot(Re, Im, max_iter, zoom):
    c = complex(Re, Im)
    z = 0.0j

    for i in range(max_iter):
        z = (z*z) + c
        if(z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag) >= 4:
            return i

    return max_iter


zoom = 1
for i in range(50):


    columns = 1920
    rows = 1080

    result = numpy.zeros([rows, columns])
    for row_index, Re in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-2, 1, num = rows)):
        for column_index, Im in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-1, 1, num = columns)):
            result[row_index, column_index] = mandlebrot(Re, Im, 50, zoom)


    plt.figure(dpi = 100)
    plt.imshow(result.T, cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'bilinear', extent = [-2, 1, -1, 1])

    zoom+=.05

    plt.xlabel('Real')
    plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
    filepath = r"C:\Users\Riley\Desktop\mandlebrot\mandlebrot" + str(i) + ".png"
    plt.savefig(filepath)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: You're doing it different than how I do it, but wouldn't you just need to change the values given to `linspace`? You just need to alter what part of the complex plane that you're looking at.

Comment: Yeah I've found that that zooms in, but my biggest trouble is keeping the middle in focus. Any ideas?

Comment: Reduce the boundaries of the plane on each side by half of the dimension. So add half the width to the left, subtract half the width from the right, add half the height to the top, and subtract half the width from the bottom. If you try to account for it all on the left/top, ya, it will skew it.

Comment: I'll just make a correction that I always forget about: when zooming in, you can't do 50% of each dimension, since a whole minus two halves is 0. Try changing the boundaries by like 20% instead.

Comment: Do you mean only on the extent = [-2, 1, -1, 1] part or for the zoom too? Sorry I'm pretty noobish and ive been staring at this screen for a while.